# How to find clusters in a matrix of values

Tags: python, 3d, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I have a 640x480 matrix that contains temperature values (coming from thermal images);
each element of the matrix represents the temperature of a single pixel like so:

```
[[31.2 30.4 32.5 ... 31.3 31.6 31.7]

 [30.0 37.4 40.5 ... 51.5 52.6 52.7]

 ...

 [28.9 28.8 28.1 ... 31.2 32.4 32.3]]
```

I want to find clusters in this matrix taking into consideration:

- temperature difference between two elements;
- positional distance between two elements;

I tried to do this by using **DBSCAN clustering algorithm** on an array containing coordinates and values of the elements like so:

```
coord = [[0 0 31.2]

         [1 0 30.4]

         [2 0 32.5]

         ...

         [638 479 32.4]

         [639 479 32.3]]
```

This is the code:

```
    X=np.array(coord)

    db = DBSCAN(eps=2, min_samples=2, metric='manhattan').fit(X)

    core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(db.labels_, dtype=bool)
    core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True
    labels = db.labels_

    n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
    n_noise_ = list(labels).count(-1)


    cluster_dict = {i: X[labels==i] for i in range(n_clusters_)}
```

The problem is that I get a large number of clusters and the clustering is not precise (also with different values ​​of eps and min_samples).
I would like to know if there is a more efficient method of doing this.

Thank you all

Comment: There are several clustering algorithms you can use. One of the most popular ones is K-Means, which is implemented in SKLearn. But be aware that it is implemented based on the euclidian distance between your data points, so it will create circular shaped clusters. If it doesn't fit your needs you can search for other clustering algorithms or even clustering ensemble algorithms.

Comment: This seems like a particularly good case for euclidean distance

Comment: Check out if MeanShift algorithm (also present in scikit learn) solves your problem (not density based, but you dont have to fix a number of clusters and it tries to fit your different data points in "spheres" that represent your clusters). In my experience with clustering it works better than DBSCAN (but my experience is very subjective ^^)